# No such filter: '-despill'

Tags: ffmpeg

I’m triying to make a good chroma key with ffmpeg but in my video there is some green spill I’ve seen there is a [despill filter](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#despill) but I cannot find an example of how to use it

When I try this command:

```
ffmpeg -i green1.jpg -vf despill=g=-1 prueba1.jpg
```

It returns the error:

```
[AVFilterGraph @ 0000000001fa89a0] No such filter: '-despill'
Error initializing complex filters.
Invalid argument
```

Can anyone provide an example of how to use it?

I have no idea of what to do with these parameters:

> **type** Set what type of despill to use.

What types are there available?

> **mix** Set how spillmap will be generated.

What value should I set?

> **expand** Set how much to get rid of still remaining spill.

Comment: The error messages don't match the command used. Run `ffmpeg -i green1.jpg -vf despill=g=-1 prueba1.jpg -report` and share the report.

Comment: my mistake, sorry

Answer (score 0):

I was wrong.

1. I had an ol version of ffmpeg, filter was in the last, I upgraded and it worked
2. I tryed with -vf and the message was from another try with -filtercomplex that also failed